# Neo4j : Match path without counting twice shared nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm working on the following Neo4j schema:

[image: Neo4j Schema]

and I'm trying to get the frequency of my different tags. I tried the following Cypher request:

```
 MATCH ()-[r:entry_tag]->(:tag_value)-[:value_of_tag]->(t:tag)
RETURN t.tag AS tag, COUNT(r) AS tagFrequency ORDER BY tagFrequency DESC
```

but my problem is that some entries have the same tag_values, but don't belong to the same tag. Thus, the ()-[:entry_tag]->() is counted each time, while I'm looking for all the unique paths from an entry to its tag.

For example, if I have the 3 following entries :

- Entry 1 : tag_value = A ; tag = tag1
- Entry 2 : tag_value = B ; tag = tag2
- Entry 3 : tag_value = A ; tag = tag3

The result I get is : (the first one is the tag and the 2nd is its frequency)

tag1 : 2

tag3 : 2

tag2 : 1

because tag 1 and 3 share the same tag value, and the relationship [:entry_value] is then counted twice while I'd like to get 1 for each frequency, as I'm trying to get the path from the beginning to the end.

I know my cypher query is wrong but I can't figure out how to correct it. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: For a better understanding, here are some graph images of my example:

First the result of the following query :

```
MATCH path= ()-[:entry_tag]->(v:tag_value)-[:value_of_tag]->(t:tag) 
WHERE t.tag in ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'] AND v.tag_value in ['A', 'B'] 
RETURN path LIMIT 3
```

[image: Query result]

Then my 3 entries and their tags and tag values:

[image: Example graph]

Comment: Looks like you're reusing the same :tag_value nodes. I'm guessing you only have one :tag_value node with the value :A, and this has two :value_of_tag relationships, one to :tag1 and the other to :tag3? Can you show us the graphical result of each of this for the 3 entries you mentioned above? `MATCH path= ()-[:entry_tag]->(v:tag_value)-[:value_of_tag]->(t:tag) 
WHERE t.tag in ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'] and v.tag_value in ['A', 'B'] RETURN path LIMIT 3`

Comment: Also, have you considered remodeling this so you have :Tag nodes with `tagName` and `tagValue` properties? That would likely make this kind of query much easier

Comment: @InverseFalcon thanks for your comment, I edited my post with the result of your query.

I considered remodeling my tags but my aim was to have one node per tag, as I have only 12 tags which I fixed before, whereas the values can be very different and numerous.

Comment: The problem with this model is you lose all context of what tag the value is associated with. Any common tag value used by multiple tags means the entry is now associated with all of those tags which have that value. Entry 1 is associated with tag1 and tag3, and I have a feeling you only wanted it associated with one of these, not both. Can you confirm your intent here?

Comment: You're right. 
I wanted to create unique nodes to be able to find the entries related to some tags more easily. 
I first thought about creating tag nodes and using the relationship properties to keep the value, but this didn't work because some entries may have more than one value for each tag, and as I'm using py2neo to create my objects it's not possible to create several relationships between two nodes. I was not convinced by using several properties on a single relationship. 
So, you're saying the best design would be a tag node with its value and its name as properties?

Comment: That's one way. Another way, similar to your model, is to not reuse the :tag_value nodes between different :entries, use separate nodes instead.

Comment: I'm trying to compare the 2 different designs, and I think the last one suits my goals better. Indeed, with your first suggestion, I can't find any simple query to count the most frequent tags and their related entries for example. I would need a 'GROUP BY' on the name property. 
Whereas as the query
    `MATCH ()-[r:value_of_tag]->(t:tag)               
    RETURN t.tag, COUNT(r) AS freq ORDER BY freq DESC`
seems to be okay for the latter